# Propagating C return codes to Haskell

Tags: c, haskell, exception, binding, ffi

This might be more of a design question; not sure how to tag this.  Also, just to be safe: I'm asking about exceptions, as in exceptional but recoverable circumstances.

If I'm writing bindings to a C library and some functions return (library-specific) error codes, set `errno`, etc. like this:

```c
ssize_t read_a_book() {
  if (i_cant_read)
    return -1;
  ...
  return numBytesRead;
}
```

What's the sanest way to propagate that to the Haskell realm? I can only think of:

- Make a new exception type to wrap C error stuff, and throw an `IO` exception whenever something horrible happens.

  ```hs
  data CSideException = CSideException String
    deriving (Show)

  instance Exception CSideException

  throwCSideException :: CSideException -> IO ()
  throwCSideException = throwIO
  ```
- Same thing, but instead of an `IO` exception, use `Either`/`ErrorT`/whatever

  ```hs
  -- Part of the binding code/thin layer on top of C call that actually notices the error
  readABook :: ErrorT CSideException IO Int
  readABook = do retval <- c_read_a_book
                 if (retval == -1) then throwError $ CSideException "Stuff happens"
                                   else return retval

  -- User of the haskell binding
  lrn2read = goToLibrary `catchError` \e -> liftIO (print e) >> return 0
    where goToLibrary = sum <$> replicateM 10 readABook
  ```

  ...or something like that.
- Bury your head in the sand

I'm semi-sure that existing Haskell libraries that bind to C code will have addressed this question; if anyone knows any good ones, that info would also be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `<!-- lanuage: blah -->` comments before code blocks to make them highlight properly, and getting things to indent properly in lists requires moving in 4 spaces (I think; I just slap spacebar until it works.). Anyway, I found [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Foreign-C-Error.html), if it helps any (not an answer because I just Googled it and I have never used FFI).

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was doing something wrong with the code sections. Also thanks for the link, can't believe I missed that. Unfortunately that module seems to be for use with system errno's; I'm more asking about "internal" errno's, e.g. In here: https://github.com/LuaDist/gsl/blob/master/err/gsl_errno.h (just googled for whatever). That, and of course, return values reserved for communicating failure.

Comment: This is kind of an opinion-based question, but it it relevant to the part of the code handling the exception that it’s an exception propagated from C? Does that affect the handler that tries to recover from the operation, or is that just a detail of some other code it interacts with? Does this kind of exception need to contain different information?

Comment: Also, and perhaps more relevant to your specific alternatives: is recovering from the exception going to require `IO` actions or not? Will data inside the exception need to be bound to `IO` operations?

Comment: I hate to say this, but I think it just depends. For the particular thing I'm working on right now, the C-side exceptions all have to do with I/O (e.g. invalid block address, file not found), so I guess recovering from that inevitably will have to be in `IO`. I can imagine other situations, though, like in [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-gsl-0.18.0.1/docs/Numeric-GSL-Integration.html). If the max iterations is exceeded, then an IO exception (via `error`) is thrown, but I think having an `Either` type exception might also make sense, if the integration routine is pure...

Comment: ...because then upon catching a `Left MaxIterExceeded` or something, someone might want to try a different method. In that case no `IO` is required. Just my opinion, though.

Comment: Oops; I shouldn't say that `error` throws an IO exception; rather, that what it throws can only be handled in `IO`.

Comment: If the bound C function is in IO, throw exceptions. If it is a pure function, return Either/ErrorT. On top, wrap the result in Maybe if it can be a null pointer.